# Passing variable to child function javascript

Tags: javascript

I've looked at multiple questions in search for an answer however to no avail, I'm trying to obtain the variable from a parent function and passing it like `"a(b)"` doesn't seem to work
I cannot for the life of me obtain 'item_classes', is there another way in which I can write my code in order for it to be operable

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.nm-more').hover(function () {
        var item_num = $(this).data('stg-id');
        var item_names = $(this).data('stg-items');
        var item_classes = $(this).data('stg-class');
            item_names.forEach(function (entry) {
            var item_index = item_classes[entry];
            alert(entry + ' ' + item_index);
        });});

    });
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bgzkge65/25/

Comment: What exactly do you want?  What kind of data does `item_classes` and `item_names` contain? Could you give us a little more context?

Comment: is this what you're trying to achieve? http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/185/ the full object is displayed in the console.

Comment: @Mouser item_classes and item_names contain an array of information ie ["Eggs","Milk","Bacon"] and ["eggclass","milkclass","baconclass"]

Comment: @Especially it seems that those arrays are stored in a `data-attribute`? Am I correct?

Comment: Yes precicesly @Mouser Here's a jsfiddle to provide more context http://jsfiddle.net/bgzkge65/25/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved:

http://jsfiddle.net/bgzkge65/27/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.nm-more').click(function () {
        var item_num = $(this).data('stg-id');
        var item_names = $(this).data('stg-items');
        var item_classes = ($(this).data('stg-class'));

        item_names.forEach(function (entry) {

            var item_index = item_classes[item_names.indexOf(entry)];
            alert(entry + ' ' + item_index);
        });

    });
});
```

And HTML changes:

```
            <li class="nm-more" data-stg-id="2" data-stg-items='["Mark as read", "Mark as unread", "Flag all items", "Unflag all items"]' data-stg-class='["readit", "unreadit", "flagit", "unflagit"]'>Mark all</li>
            <li class="nm-more" data-stg-id="1" data-stg-items='["Mark as read", "Mark as unread", "Flag items", "Unflag items"]' data-stg-class='["readit", "unreadit", "flagit", "unflagit"]'>Selected</li>
```

What I did:

First of all: `data-stg-class` wasn't formatted as an array. I reformatted and made it an array.

The code was actually correct, but you are using named keys, but you need to use indexes here. So `entry` should be an index and not a reference to a named key from `data-stg-class`. So I used `item_names.indexOf(entry)` to retrieve the proper index and return the correct value.

---

Instead of `array.indexOf`, you could also retrieve the index from `forEach`. It's the second argument of that function, either declare it in the function declaration or retrieve it with `arguments[1]`. In this case the indexes of both arrays match which makes this alternative solution viable.

Comment: Ah, you are a life saver! I completely forgot about the 'indexOf' bit, works like a charm thank you!